# Ruby using regex in select block

Tags: ruby, regex, select

I've been having a lot of trouble sifting out regex matches. I could use scan, but since it only operates over a string, and I dont want to use a join on the array in question, it is much more tedious. I want to be able to do something like this:

```
array = ["a1d", "6dh","th3"].select{|x| x =~ /\d/}
# => ["1", "6", "3"}
```

However this never seems to work. Is there a work around or do I just need to use scan?

Comment: Can `array = ["abc", "66dh", "th-3"]`? If `array` might include `"abc"`, what should it be mapped to in the array that is returned (e.g., `nil`)?

Comment: I've begun to wonder why I should bother asking questions intended to clarify questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try: **[Array#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map)**

```
> array = ["a1d", "6dh","th3"].map {|x| x[/\d+/]}
#=> ["1", "6", "3"]
```

**Note:**
**[select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-select)**

> Returns a new array containing all elements of ary for which the given
>   block returns a true value.

In your case each element contains digit and it returns true, so you are getting original element via `select`. while `map` will perform action on each element and return new array with performed action on each element.

Comment: @Gagan_Gami Your solution works. Could you explain the misunderstanding I have? I thought what would happen is, using select, it would return the array of matches, and array would be assigned to it. Why is that not happening?

Comment: Depending on the OP's requirements, maybe `/-?\d+/`.

Comment: @WillAshley: Updated my answer with little explanation.

Comment: @CarySwoveland : May be. I am not good at REGEX so not clear with difference but it worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`grep`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep) with a block:

```
array = ["a1d", "6dh", "th3"]

array.grep(/(\d)/) { $1 }
#=> ["1", "6", "3"]
```

It passes each matching element to the block and returns an array containing the block's results.

`$1` is a [special global variable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Special+global+variables) containing the first capture group.

Unlike `map`, only matching elements are returned:

```
array = ["a1d", "foo", "6dh", "bar", "th3"]

array.grep(/(\d)/) { $1 }
#=> ["1", "6", "3"]

array.map { |s| s[/\d/] }
#=> ["1", nil, "6", nil, "3"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirements, you may wish to construct a hash.

```
arr = ["a1d", "6dh", "th3", "abc", "3for", "rg6", "def"]

arr.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }) { |str,h| h[str[/\d+/]] << str }
  #=> {"1"=>["a1d"], "6"=>["6dh", "rg6"], "3"=>["th3", "3for"], nil=>["abc", "def"]}
```

`Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }` creates an empty hash with a default block, represented by the block variable `h`. That means that if the hash does not have a key `k`, the block is executed, adding the key value pair `k=>[]` to the hash, after which `h[k] << k` is executed.

The above is a condensed (and Ruby-like) way of writing the following.

```
h = {}
arr.each do |str|
  s = str[/\d+/]
  h[s] = [] unless h.key?(s)
  h[s] << str
end
h
  # => {"1"=>["a1d"], "6"=>["6dh", "rg6"], "3"=>["th3", "3for"], nil=>["abc", "def"]}
```

The expression in the third line could alternatively be written

```
arr.each_with_object({}) { |str,h| (h[str[/\d+/]] ||= []) << str }
```

`h[str[/\d+/]] ||= []` sets `h[str[/\d+/]]` to an empty array if the hash `h` does not have a key `str[/\d+/]`.

See [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) and [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-c-new).

@Stefan suggests

```
arr.group_by { |str| str[/\d+/] }
  #=> {"1"=>["a1d"], "6"=>["6dh", "rg6"], "3"=>["th3", "3for"], nil=>["abc", "def"]}
```

What can I say?

Comment: Or simply `arr.group_by { |str| str[/\d+/] }`